# Is there any way to debug meteor-jasmine client-side unit tests?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, meteor, jasmine, meteor-jasmine

I'm writing a small meteor app and simultanously I'm trying to practice TDD. I've run into a small hurdle in that I can't figure out how I can run my Jasmine unit tests through a debugger.

The tests are stored in `[project root]/tests/jasmine/client/unit` as in the example.

The velocity docs detail how to debug the server-side tests [here](https://velocity.readme.io/docs/debugging), but it doesn't mention client-side tests.

I can debug client integration tests; when starting meteor it logs `[velocity] jasmine-client-integration is starting a mirror at http://localhost:51259/.`, and by going there it's possible to debug my tests. But no mirror seems to be created for the client unit tests?

EDIT: in fact it seems like I can debug the client integration tests at `localhost:3000` as well. The developer console looks like this:

[image: Chrome developer console]

and by adding a breakpoint in miscSpec.js I can debug my integration tests.

Lastly, I know that Meteor-Jasmine writes the output from console.log in the unit tests to `[project root]/.meteor/local/log/jasmine-client-unit.log`. That is serviceable, but I would prefer to be able to run the tests through a debugger, since I find it easier to figure out what I did wrong.

I'm using

- meteor 1.2.0.2
- sanjo:jasmine 0.20.2

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I have moved all my client unit tests from `[project root]/tests/jasmine/client/unit` to `[project root]/tests/jasmine/client/integration`. There does not seem to make much of a difference whether unit tests are run as unit tests or integration tests. In fact, the [Velocity docs](https://velocity.readme.io/docs/jasmine-testing-modes) has almost the exact same description of the two modes.

It would be nicer to be able to debug the tests in a view where you can also select which tests that should be run, just when running Jasmine normally, but perhaps this is in the works.